# How to display the latest Update from each Category per Project?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a page that displays a snapshot of projects in a list of boxes, each box has project owner, title date, that kind of thing, there is also a window within that separates the updates into 7 categories, the updates are in a separate table. Looping through the projects is fine, but the updates come from all the projects. How do I filter out the other projects?

I can post my code, but I have done this 2 or 3 times in the past month with no response so suspecting that my structure is completely wrong.

To give you an example of what I am after, to be able to pull out the latest update that is filtered for Project id, and then update category. Is this possible?

EDIT: adding template and css so you can hopefully see graphically what it is I am trying to do.

models.py:

```
from datetime import datetime
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission, User
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse


User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL


class Area(models.Model):
    '''
    Project area - Digital, Uplink, DTH VoD, Interactive, OTT Streaming,
    OTT VoD, OTT Platform, Operational Improvement, Archive.
    '''
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45, unique=True)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=45, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Priority(models.Model):
    '''
    Project priority - Low, Medium, High - defualt set to Low
    '''
    priority = models.CharField(max_length=16, unique=True)
    colour = models.CharField(max_length=7, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.priority


class Project(models.Model):
    '''
    Main Project, serves the default Projects Portal window.
    '''
    date_published = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    area = models.ForeignKey(Area, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    summary = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    others = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True)
    deadline = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    priority = models.ForeignKey(Priority, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    closed = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class UpdateCategory(models.Model):
    '''
    Updates are split into 6 categories that applies to each project
    with 2 extra categories of Other Updates and Mitigating issues.
    '''
    name = models.CharField(max_length=24, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Update(models.Model):
    '''
    Latest update must have a category from UpdateCategory
    and be linked to a project, all updates are timestamped.
    '''
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ForeignKey(UpdateCategory, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    update = models.TextField(max_length=2048, blank=True)
    added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.update
```

So each project has it's updates (update to the state of the project) split into 7 different categories as each project follows the same structure, the last category "other updates" being an catchall for issues/blockers to the project, being able to see the last update from each project in one small block gives a nice overview of where the project is at a quick glance. Visually, each project will be shown as a block showing the last update for each category. I am thinking that I need to set up a function that picks the latest update from each category (a blank or null value is completely valid and should just be blank or white space), but I can't work out how this will be filtered for each project as the looping happens within the template at the moment.

```html
{% extends "project_portal/base.html" %}
{% block home %}

<div id="main">
  <div id="content">
    <hgroup>
      <h1>OTT</h1>
      <h2>Service Integration Development Project Portal</h2>
    </hgroup
  </div>
  {% if object_list %}
  {% for project in project_list %}
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box1">
      <h4>{{ project.title }}</h4>
      <p>Project Status</p>
      <div class="square"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="box2">
      <strong>{{ project.summary }}</strong>
    </div>

    <div class="box3">
      <strong>{{ project.user }}</strong>
    </div>

    <div class="box4">
      <table class="items">
        <col width="160px">
        <tr class="updates">
          <!-- <td>Monitoring Status</td> -->
          <td><a href="{{ project.id }}/update">Impact Scenario</a></td>
          <td>&#x2705;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="updates">
          <td><a href="{{ project.id }}/update">Support Model</a></td>
          <td>&#x2705;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="updates">
          <td><a href="{{ project.id }}/update">Monitoring Status</a></td>
          <td>&#x2705;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="updates">
          <td><a href="{{ project.id }}/update">Training</a></td>
          <td>&#x2705;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="updates">
          <td><a href="{{ project.id }}/update">Service Rehearsals</a></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="updates">
          <td><a href="{{ project.id }}/update">Documentation</a></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="updates">
          <td><a href="{{ project.id }}/update">Other Updates</a></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>

    <div class="box5">
      {% for item in update_category %}
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>{{ update.id }}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <div class="box6">
      <h4>Project Timeline</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="box7">TimeLine</div>
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: When looping through your project you could use `if` statements to check the value of the project. Or just predefine the subset of projects that you want in the view `context`.

Comment: Could you post the bit where you iterate over the projects and try to show the updates? So I mean the template part. Showing how you pass `updates` would also help.

Comment: Please show your models.py and remove useless css. Please elaborate what are "updates", "categories" and how they are related. `and then update category` what do you mean by "update"?

Comment: I have updated this as requested and still stuck. Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Very confused, why have I been asked to edit my post only to get no help at all?